# NPM Start is BROKEN

Tags: npm

I have trashed folder/ file/ entire project and restarted. I have uninstalled NPM, updated Node.js. When i `npm start` I get this error repeated.

I am also unable to deploy to Netifly.

````
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/erikastigleman/.npm/_logs/2021-11-21T07_50_56_543Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Can you post full command output and your project folder structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file add the script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
},
```

In this case when I run npm start it runs my index.js file.
Change it to the file you want to run.